# “Rapporter” vs “apporter” -- to talk about the potential ensuing benefits

Tags: expressions

> Qu'est-ce que ça vous **rapporte** de venir ici cette nuit ?
>
> versus: Qu'est-ce que ça vous **apporte** de venir ici cette nuit ?

Does “rapporter” refer to **monetary** gains in particular, whereas “apporter” encompasses **all kinds of** benefits ensuing from taking a particular action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, *rapporter* has several meanings but in the first sentence, the person asking the question expects that there might be a benefit that will increase the assets of the other person(s) while in the second sentence using *apporter*, the range of expected benefits is wider. For example, in addition to a material payoff, it might be intellectual, health, fame…

Of course, even in the first case, the answer might nevertheless state the gain won't be financial but any possible benefit.